# Error with webdriver-manager/selenium when creating executable with Pyinstaller

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have tried doing a lot of research online to find how to fix this but I can't seem to find anything that helps.

Basically i want to create an executable so that I can wake my laptop using WakeUpOnStandby (I am open to other methods for this). My code runs perfectly when I use anaconda to run my script but after creating an executable I get an error message as below.

I create the executable using the below, I added the hidden import from something I read online but doesn't seem to work:

```
pyinstaller --onefile nhl.py --hidden-import=selenium
```

The key parts of my code are as follows:

```
import requests
import openpyxl as xl
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import shutil
import os
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

#Bunch of options and shit for the webdriver
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
#chrome_options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
chrome_options.binary_location = "C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
chrome_options.headless = True
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
```

And the error message I get is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "XXX\NHL\NHL.py", line 5, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 29, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 26, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 43, in <module>
  File "pkgutil.py", line 639, in get_data
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 344, in get_data
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\XXX\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\_MEI138322\\selenium\\webdriver\\remote\\getAttribute.js'
[19888] Failed to execute script 'NHL' due to unhandled exception!
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a fix that will allow the executable to run, it isn't ideal but will work for now.

replacing this line

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options = chrome_options)
```

with

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\\PATH\\chromedriver.exe", options = chrome_options)
```

Fixes it, however I will have to manually update the chromedriver file if it stops working. Which could happen if it becomes outdated enough and doesn't work with the current google chrome version.